# MultivaluedSection Async Row Insertion

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

So I'm using Eureka for creating e form on my iOS APP, and I'm at a point where I want to use a `MultivaluedSection` to add a list of people to the form.

This is the a standard implementation of it:

```
MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete],
                           header: "Multivalued TextField",
                           footer: ".Insert multivaluedOption adds the 'Add New Tag' button row as last cell.") {
            $0.tag = "textfields"
            $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
                return ButtonRow(){
                    $0.title = "Add New Tag"
                }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
                    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
                }
            }
            $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in

                return NameRow() {
                    $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                }
            }
        }
```

The Key here is the `$0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt` method, it returns a `BaseRow` instance of the row you want, it runs whenever I tap the Button row as expected.

However I do not want to create the row right away, the snippet bellow demonstrates the functionality I want to achieve, basically I need to do some preparation and fetch data from a server before adding the row to the section. However its a dummy exemple since I can't return the parent closure from the inner one.

```
$0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in

                let row = NameRow() {
                    $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                }

                let AC = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Async Test", preferredStyle: .alert)

                AC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Row", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

                    return row

                }))

                self.present(AC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

I wonder if somebody can give me a hint of what can I do to achieve this functionality.

I'm planning to create a custom row for helping me in another ways, but I don't know if a custom cell can resolve the main issue I'm having right now.